# React chained setState breaking render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a RadioInput component in react however when I add a callback to set the state inside of the parent the buttons do not remain clicked down.

Inside of the RadioInput components render function I am creating the internal buttons like so:

```
this.props.buttons.map( (button) => {
    return (
        <div ...>
            <Button clickedDown={this.state.selectedButton === button} clickAction={() => this.radioSelected(button)}.../>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The radio selected function then sets the internal radio input state to have the button clicked become the selected button and calls the function passed to the child to give the value of the option to the parent

```
radioSelected = (button) => {
    if (this.state.selectedButton !== button) {
        this.setState({selectedButton: button}, () => {
            this.props.clickAction(this.state.selectedButton);
        }
    }
}
```

The RadioInput is declared like this inside of the parent:

```
render () {
    const buttonList = [
        { color:'green', text:'Green', id: 1 },
        { color:'blue', text:'Blue', id: 2 },
        { color:'purple', text:'Purple', id: 3 }
    ];
    return (
        <RadioInput buttons={buttonList} clickAction={this.radioAction}/>
    )
}
```

The radioAction function that is called by the RadioInput's internal radioSelected function looks like this:

```
radioAction = (button) => {
    this.setState({
        team: button.color
    });
}
```

If I remove `this.props.clickAction(this.state.selectedButton);` from the `setState` inside the radio input it functions properly. If I remove the `setState` inside of the parents `radioAction()` if functions correctly. Why are the chained setStates causing errors, like stopping the `clickedDown={this.state.selectedButton === button}` to not be reevaluated?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe if you could illustrate what you're trying to do I can help you but It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve

Comment: In the radioInput when you press a button it makes the button go into a clickedDown state. When the user clicks that I want to send the value of the button to the parent (the overall form) so it can use that data when submitting the form. When I use it the state of both gets set correctly but the button does not go into the clickedDown state.

Comment: if your state is being set correctly, then have you tried if this clickedDown prop actually works? Like maybe setting it to static true and see what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tl; dr;

```
x0 = [{a: 'red'}];
x1 = [{a: 'red'}];
console.log(x0[0] === x1[0]); // false
```

Move initialization of `buttonList` (`const buttonList = ...`) from `render` function to constructor or any other place that doesn't change the array on each render.

#### Explanation

In your parent you reinitialize `buttonList` each time `render` is called. So after each call to parent's `render` you have a different `buttonList`, because it is a newly created object each time.

Now, your `radioAction` function calls `setState` on parent, which invokes `render` and effectively changes all items of `buttonList` to a new array of items. And definitely `this.state.selectedButton` isn't equal to any of them, as it is an item from the former array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `clickAction` does not receive parameters:

```
clickAction={() => this.radioSelected(button)}
```

It broke because you called it with a parameter meanwhile `clickAction` prop does not receive your parameter, so it just doesn't receive `this.state.selectedButton`

```
this.props.clickAction(this.state.selectedButton);
```

So, it should be:

```
clickAction={(button) => this.radioSelected(button)}
```

Comment: This actually causes more issues, if I give a parameter it binds it as the Proxy. I'm using the closure to bind the scope so it has access to button. When I print out the `button` in `radioSelected()` as the code is currently it correctly gets the button value `{ color:'green', text:'Green', id: 1 }`. Like I said the code works perfectly fine until I add the line `this.props.clickAction(this.state.selectedButton);` inside of RadioInputs `setState` callback.

Comment: I will note that if I take out the `setState` in the parents `radioAction` function the code also works correctly. I am looking for why have sequential `setStates` causes errors